# How would I run a option on buttonclick and also add a function to the option

Tags: javascript, html

Basically what I want to do is, if GATE1 is selected from the dropdown menu then run evinar() function on button click, otherwise if GATE2 is selected from the dropdown menu then run evinar2 function on button click.

```
<select name="gates" id="gates">
  <option value="gates">GATES</option>
  <option value="1">GATE1</option>
  <option value="2">GATE2</option>
</select>
<button class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 360px; outline: none;" id="testar" onclick="enviar()">➤「Start」</button>


 <script title="ajax do checker">
    function enviar() {
      var linha = $("#lista").val();
      var linhaenviar = linha.split("\n");
      var total = linhaenviar.length;
      var ap = 0;
      var rp = 0;
      linhaenviar.forEach(function(value, index) {
        setTimeout(
          function() {
            $.ajax({
              url: 'api.php?lista=' + value,
              type: 'GET',
              async: true,
              success: function(resultado) {
                if (resultado.match("#Approved")) {
                  removelinha();
                  ap++;
                  aprovadas(resultado + "");
                } else {
                  removelinha();
                  rp++;
                  reprovadas(resultado + "");
                }
                $('#carregadas').html(total);
                var fila = parseInt(ap) + parseInt(rp);
                $('#cLive').html(ap);
                $('#cDie').html(rp);
                $('#total').html(fila);
                $('#cLive2').html(ap);
                $('#cDie2').html(rp);
              }
            });
          }, 2500 * index);
      });
    }
    function evinar2() {
      var linha = $("#lista").val();
      var linhaenviar = linha.split("\n");
      var total = linhaenviar.length;
      var ap = 0;
      var rp = 0;
      linhaenviar.forEach(function(value, index) {
        setTimeout(
          function() {
            $.ajax({
              url: 'api2.php?lista=' + value,
              type: 'GET',
              async: true,
              success: function(resultado) {
                if (resultado.match("#Approved")) {
                  removelinha();
                  ap++;
                  aprovadas(resultado + "");
                } else {
                  removelinha();
                  rp++;
                  reprovadas(resultado + "");
                }
                $('#carregadas').html(total);
                var fila = parseInt(ap) + parseInt(rp);
                $('#cLive').html(ap);
                $('#cDie').html(rp);
                $('#total').html(fila);
                $('#cLive2').html(ap);
                $('#cDie2').html(rp);
              }
            });
          }, 2500 * index);
      });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to go around this depending on how you want to tackle it. If this button click is the same that would submit your form, then might want to serialize the form data, and get the value of this field. Look into [.serializeArray() from jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

Otherwise, you'd select the field by id and get its value. Typically, I'd create a third function that is triggered on click. The new function would get the field value and then call either functions depending on the value. Check out the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/s4ek1389/pen/MbarmG?editors=1100).

```
<select name="gates" id="gates">
  <option value="gates">GATES</option>
  <option value="1">GATE1</option>
  <option value="2">GATE2</option>
</select>
<button onclick="functionSelector()">➤「Start」</button>
<script>
// this function will route your request
function functionSelector() {
  var e = document.getElementById("gates");
  var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  if(value === "1")
    enviar();
  else if (value === "2")
    evinar2();
  else
    unknownOption();
}

function enviar() {
  alert('enviar')
}

function evinar2() {
  alert('enviar 2')
}

function unknownOption () {
  alert('Unexpected answer')
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're already using jQuery, you could do it like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").on("change", function() {
      if ($(this).children("option:selected").val() == 1) {
         evinar();
      } 
      else if ($(this).children("option:selected").val() == 2) {
         evinar2();
     }
   });
 });
```